# Cannot change property Geom value to NpgsqlTypes.Postgis Point

Tags: postgis, npgsql

I have problem with `St_Distance` throwing a cast to Point exception. The problem is with npgsql as the same command works in pgadmin.

```
select st_distance(
           st_geomfromtext('POINT (14.519407135154106 40.057968029195614)',4326)
           ,rawgeom )
from public.mon_trackpoint 
limit 1
```

I get the response

> Cannot change property Geom value to NpgsqlTypes.Postgis Point

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more detail about what you're doing? A small code sample of C# code, please the type of the rawgeom column would be a good start.

Comment: i solve it by add cast